# How to connect to google cloud docker service using python in cloud run

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform

I would like to connect to a docker service from a cloud run serverless with python. For example when I run this inside a cloud run service:

```
import docker
client = docker.from_env()
```

I get this error: `docker.errors.DockerException: Error while fetching server API version: ('Connection aborted.', FileNotFoundError(2, 'No such file or directory'))`

I should create `env` file but I don't know what should be the content of this file.

I want to open and close various containers using this docker client.
What should I specify in my env file to connect to my GCP project?

Comment: If you want docker on Cloud Run, your container must contain docker service. However, I don't know if it will work. Try with gen2 execution runtime...

Comment: There are some major security concerns with directly using the Docker socket, and I wouldn't be surprised if this wasn't available in a hosted public-cloud setup.  You say "connect to a service", which shouldn't require the Docker API; what are you trying to do with the `client` object once you have it?

Comment: Execute a few Linux commands and then close the container @DavidMaze

Comment: A container normally runs only a single process.  Can you encapsulate "a few Linux commands" inside a dedicated server, and trigger it via an HTTP request or using a message queue like RabbitMQ?  That won't require the Docker API at runtime, and it will be easier to run in other environments.